# How can I create a new file in the Windows FTP Terminal

Tags: windows, file, ftp

`mkdir` works in both windows cmd and the Windows FTP terminal:

```
ftp> mkdir newDir
257 "newDir" : The directory was successfully created
ftp> cd newDir
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/newDir
```

To create a new file in Windows cmd: `copy NUL EMptyFile.txt`. This, however, does not work in the Windows FTP terminal. How can I create a new file in the Windows FTP Terminal?

Comment: afaik you cannot do that. Create the file first, start the ftp session, upload the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute any local Windows command from `ftp.exe` with the `!` prefix (command):

```
!copy NUL EMptyFile.txt
```